# Connecting bass to a laptop

Tags: amplifiers, electric-bass-guitar, computer

I'm learning the bass by myself and have been at it for 2 weeks now. I've been using the VOX AP2BS bass amp that goes directly into my headphones.

However, I think it'll be more convenient if I can hear the output from my laptop.

I connected the amp to my laptop using an aux cable and tinkered every possible microphone setting but couldn't get the sound from laptop speakers. My laptop runs Windows 10.

I don't wish to record, just be able to hear my bass.

Comment: Doubtful if the sound quality will be as good from the laptop speakers. They're hardly designed for bass - but the bass amp, conveniently, is!

Comment: I feel like I'm too new to worry about my bass sounding good. I'm basically practicing very basic exercises and working on muting. But point taken. Thanks.

Comment: Better you sound the better you play! Also, you'll hear subtle things more with the amp, which should sort out little 'mistakes' sooner.

Comment: There may be significant impedance mismatch between your bass amp output and the laptop input.  But in any case, it's much easier for headphones to reproduce the deep bass than for speakers less than maybe 8-inch diameter

Comment: Did you make sure the Vox was turned all the way up when you tried?  You can also test using your phone.  If you can play your phone through your laptop via an Aux cable, then you're golden.

Comment: Reading all the above comments, I think I'll stick with headphones. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are all good, but you could also get a **digital audio interface**. This connects to your computer via USB, and you can plug your bass right into it. It won't sound as good as a real amp, but you'll have much more control over the sound.